# Ubuntu Installer didn't detect my current OS

Tags: 14.04, windows-8

When I tried to install Ubuntu 14.04, I could not find the option to install it alongside my Windows 8.1 installation - why is this the case and why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You must be trying to install from a live media. Ok now 1st thing you must try to do is restart your computer and boot into the pendrive again. If the problem solves well and good, if not try opening gparted if it reports an error it's May be a connection problem. Sometimes the files appear well and good but the partitions are not detected clearly. Try doing 'something else' on the installation see if there the windows boot loader written or not alongside any of the partitions. You may try to reconnect your hard drive.

Comment: Also try USB2.0 instead of SS-USB